# Please Help Build a List of Flow Limitations

Tags: visual-workflow, bulkification

(long post – sorry)

Hoping to solicit some feedback about flow limitations to establish some clear thresholds for when to use them versus APEX or custom Lightning Components (Web or Aura).

I and a few of my colleagues have put together some limitations that we’ve observed so far, categorized by general vs. bulk handling with collections. Can you please help us with the following?

1. Are any of these limitations incorrect / is there a way around them natively in flows without APEX ormcustom Lightning Components that we’re not thinking of?
2. Is there anything you’d like to add to this list?

Thanks so much in advance!

## **Possible Limitations of Flows**

**GENERAL**

- In a record trigger flow, you are unable to call sub-flows.
- Like having multiple triggers on the same object, Salesforce has no way of guaranteeing in which order the record triggered flows would execute for the same object.

  - Best practice, to ensure bulkification, would then dictate that a trigger with a handler class should be used to set criteria for when specific auto-launched flows should be executed.
  - If bulkification is unnecessary, then a process builder (one per object) should be used to set criteria and the order of execution for calling flows.
  - If the above handlers aren’t used, you would either end up with multiple record triggered flows (and the situation above) OR, if you maintain ONE record triggered flow per object, you could end up with an extremely hard to maintain and massive flow with tons of decision elements.
- You are unable to, without calling APEX in the flow, utilize the “LIMIT” operator of a SOQL query aside from a LIMIT 1.
- There is only specific html formatting of text () that is allowed. The following HTML tags are converted to rich text: `<a>, <b>, <br>, <font>, <i>, <li>, <p>, <span>, <u>, and <div>`. HTML that is pasted into the rich text editor is not supported.
- Rich text fields are not supported in screen components.

**IN THE CONTEXT WHERE YOU ARE BULKIFYING THE FLOW WITH COLLECTIONS**

- There is no concept of a MAP when building a flow, so when you need to retrieve a parent record after selecting it into a record collection, instead of being able to match the child's lookup Id to the parent Id quickly, you end up having a second inner-loop to find the parent Id, then manipulate the values, then move onto the next child record, having to re-loop through all of the parent records again. Essentially, during these loops parent Ids must be stored in a comma-separated text collection versus a record collection directly which forces more SOQL queries.
- The above can be reversed as well. If you are trying to update multiple children at the same time without APEX called in the flow, you will need multiple loops and may exceed SOQL query limits.
- You are unable to, without calling APEX in the flow, utilize the “IN” operator of a SOQL query based on the comma separated IDs in a text collection like the one described above.
- Without calling APEX in the flow, time-out errors may be encountered frequently while processing even with just a couple hundred records for more complex use cases (think the situations above).